# Angular / Firebase - How to use *ngFor on object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I have**

- A component that displays details on an 'Issue'
- Inside the issue I have another node called 'images'
- Inside the image node I'll have further properties, such as 'image_title'

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- My Issue component can display all data related to an issue
- However, an issue may have multiple images under the image node
- I would like to also loop through the image node and display all 'image_title' properties

**Error**
I receive the following error with the code below:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**Question**

- How would this be possible?

**Issue List Resolver**

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {

            this.authService.user
                .first()
                .subscribe(user => {

                    const projectId = route.params['projectId'];
                    const issueId = route.params['issueId'];

                    this.database.object(`/issue/${projectId}/${issueId}`)
                        .first()
                        .subscribe(issue => {
                            observer.next(issue);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                });
        });
    }
```

**Issue Component**
imagesToDisplay is:

'imagesToDisplay: FirebaseListObservable;'

```
    this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { issueData: any, issueImageData: any }) => {
        this.issueToDisplay = data.issueData;
        this.imagesToDisplay =  data.issueData.images;
        console.log(this.imagesToDisplay);
      });
```

**Issue Component HTML**

There's a comment in the HTML where I'm trying to loop through the images.

```
<ul class="vs__details__ul">

  <li class="vs__details__li" *ngIf="issueToDisplay.issue_title">
    <div class="vs__label"> Issue Title </div>
    <div class="vs__data"> {{ issueToDisplay.issue_title }} </div>
  </li>

  <li class="vs__details__li" *ngIf="issueToDisplay.issue_comments">
    <div class="vs__label"> Issue Comments </div>
    <div class="vs__data"> {{ issueToDisplay.issue_comments }} </div>
  </li>

  <li class="vs__details__li">
    <div class="vs__label"> Images </div>
    <!-- LOOP THROUGH IMAGES HERE -->
    <div class="issue__images" *ngFor="let image of imagesToDisplay">

    <div class="vs__data"> {{ image.image_title }}</div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**JSON Structure from Firebase**

[image]

**The Console - (from the console.log in the component)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you need to turn your images (which is an object literal) into an iterable so `*ngFor` recognizes it. You can add all the images into an array before passing it to `imagesToDisplay`:

```
const images = [];
for (const image of Object.keys(data.issueData.images)) {
 images.push(data.issueData.images[image]);
}
this.imagesToDisplay = images;
```

Make a function to do it for you:

```
interface Image {
  image_title: string;
}
// ...

function getIterableImages(images: any): Image[] {
  const arrayImages = [];

  // returns empty array if input is not defined
  if (images == undefined) return arrayImages;

  // returns an array of first level elements inside of object
  for (const key of Object.keys(images)) {
    if (images[key] != undefined) {
      arrayImages.push(images[key]);
    }
  }
  return arrayImages;
}
// ...

this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { issueData: any, issueImageData: any }) => {
        this.issueToDisplay = data.issueData;
        this.imagesToDisplay = getIterableImages(data.issueData.images);
        console.log(this.imagesToDisplay);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks Praiser - I get the following error when going for the second option: Type 'Map<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Map<string, any>'.

Comment: Opps, so `*ngFor` doesn't support `Map` yet, it has to be array

Comment: I updated my answer! I didn't know `ngFor` doesn't support `Map`s, that's because `ngFor` needs the length of elements.

Comment: ah amazing! This is so close! This works for items that have data under the images node. For when there isn't the following error is thrown: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" - Possibly an *ngIf check in the HTML?

Comment: Or a check to see if the returned value is bigger than one, if so, call the 'getIterableImages' function?

Comment: I added those corner cases as well.

Comment: You can return the result of `getIterableImages` in @Rajez's proposal of using pipes to have the best solution ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom pipe `keys` for getting list of `keys` of an `Object`

```
// pipes.ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        if(value instanceof Object) return Object.keys(value);
        else return [];
    }
}
```

Include the new custom pipe in `app.module.ts`

```
// app.module.ts
import { KeysPipe } from './pipes.ts;

@NgModule({
 declarations: [ KeysPipe ]
```

And use it to iterate over the `Object` in `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let img of images | keys">
   <p>{{x[img]['title']}}</p>
</div>
```

Images object:

```
images = {
   'img1': {'title': 'Title1'},
   'img2': {'title': 'Title2'},
   'img3': {'title': 'Title3'},
   'img4': {'title': 'Title4'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajez. I haven't used Pipes before. How do I associate my data with the pipe?

Comment: Good idea, just return an array of object instead of only keys.

Comment: Updated the answer @ETX.

Comment: Thanks Rajez. I've just tried your way too. It seems close. I've added       <div *ngFor="let image of imagesToDisplay | keys">
          <p>{{['image_title']}}</p>
     </div>

Comment: And it brings back two items...which there are! (good start). But it just shows the string 'image_title' (as you'd expect) How do I get the actual values out?

Comment: Also, like with @praiser's proposal, the following error occurs when there are issues that don't have images: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @ETX access current looping `image` as `{{imagesToDisplay[image]['image_title']}}`

Comment: Rajez, thank you very much for looking into this. I wish I could mark them both as answers as I appreciate you both taking the time to teach me something.