# How can I use Angular4 *ngFor to create a data table?

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngfor

I am working on a project using Angular4 to get data from an API and using*ngFor to render a data table. Because I still have more aips with same structure, I want to use (key, value) pair to display them. In AngularJS, I have correctly rendered the table like this:

```html
<!--This is Good in AngularJS-->
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.items[0]"> {{key}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat ="data in data.items >
        <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">{{ value }}</td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the table doesn't show in Angular4 correctly. The original json data from API shows like:

```js
{
    items: [
    {
        status: "Sold - Payment Received",
        count: 30,
        loans: 8,
        dl_loans: 8,
        avg_available: 149.5,
        min: 28,
        max: 346,
        principal: 13452.37,
        closed: 0,
        chrg_of_balance: 0,
        final_balance: 0
    },
    {
        status: "At Auction - Awaiting Info",
        count: 4,
        loans: 4,
        dl_loans: 4,
        avg_available: 70.45,
        min: 36,
        max: 102,
        principal: 11727.8,
        closed: 0,
        chrg_of_balance: 0,
        final_balance: 0
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is my app.component.ts:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data.items;
        this.titles = data.items[0];
      }
    );
}
```

I have created a pip.ts for filter key and value:

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

In Angular4 HTML:

```html
<!--This is Bad in Angular4-->
<table>
 <thead align="center">
     <tr>
         <th *ngFor = "let item of titles | keys"> 
           {{item.key}}
         </th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td *ngFor = "let item of data | keys "> 
        {{item.value | json }}
      </td>           
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

However the thead in UI shows fine, but the tbody part shows including the whole object (partly):

```
    status 
---------------------------------------
{
    status: "Sold - Payment Received",
    count: 30,
    loans: 8,
    dl_loans: 8,
    avg_available: 149.5,
    min: 28,
    max: 346,
    principal: 13452.37,
    closed: 0,
    chrg_of_balance: 0,
    final_balance: 0
 }
--------------------------------------
```

Anyone knows how can I render this table correctly? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: you cannot loop `title` as title is placed to a single item from data `this.titles = data.items[0];` may be changing to data will worl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880284/7491209 this may help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a different pipe instead of what you are using that will just return the keys of your object

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core'; 
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

You should change your template code as

```html
<thead align="center">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor = "let item of titles | keys"> 
            {{item}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor = "let item of data ">
        <td *ngFor = "let key of item | keys " > 
            {{item[key]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thank you. but I have other apis have same structure but different content, which means the they all look like {items:[{.....},{.....},...]} is any way I can use (key, value) way in AngularJS to show them all instead of specific key name?

Comment: Updated my answer.Please Check

Comment: Hi @Vikhyath, thank you so much! It improved,  rendering the correct rows, but table cell is empty and throw me an error:  "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." Any hints?

Comment: sorry i forgot about that pipe.Please check the updated answer

Comment: Hi @Vikhyath, First of all thank you so much for your kind! This version is not good as last one, in this version, it still shows the whole object in tbody which like I posted and it gives me wrong row numbers. I think there must be something in <td> like you posted before: "<td *ngFor = "let key of item | keys " > ". In this way, it at least gives me right table (cols and rows). Any more clues?

Comment: BTW, do you think there are some problems with my pip?

Comment: Hi @Vikhyath, perfect! Finally, it shows perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad i coupd help :)