# How to repeat table <td></td> based on <th></th> in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am having these two arrays

```
valuesArray=[{name:"abc",num:"111",status:"available"},
             {name:"def",num:"222",status:"available"},
             {name:"ghi",num:"333",ststus:"offiline"}]    
headerArray=[{headerName:"name"},{headerName:"num"}]
```

and I want to construct a table using `*ngFor` by having `tds` that match to my header array.
Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Angular4 \*ngFor to create a data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983485/how-can-i-use-angular4-ngfor-to-create-a-data-table)

Comment: use group by pipe : please check similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443060/merge-divs-with-same-value/53520350#53520350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- Iterate over headers -->
            <th scope="col" *ngFor="let header of headerArray;">
                 {{header.headerName}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Iterate over value rows -->
        <tr *ngFor="let valueRow of valuesArray">
            <!-- Iterate over headers -->
            <td *ngFor="let header of headerArray">
                <!-- Get required value by header as key -->
                {{valueRow[header.headerName]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```